# To get the commandargument in rowdatabound event in gridview

Tags: vb.net

Following is code for buttonclick in gridview.

```
Protected Sub lnkChangeStatus_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 

    Dim gvr As GridViewRow = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow) 

    Dim lngProfileId As Long = Convert.ToInt64(gvwBusinessProfiles.DataKeys(gvr.RowIndex).Value) 

End Sub
```

I want to get commandargument of `lnkChangeStatus` in its click.Is there any way

Answer (score -1):

I guess the syntax for the eventhandler (Command event as against Click) should be as below.

```
Protected Sub lnkChangeStatus_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs) 
.....
End Sub
```

You can use e.CommandName or e.CommandArgument inside the code block.
Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx)